# I am trying to take data from "blog" and push it to "blogs", yet an error occurs

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm getting the following error:

```
**Error1:** Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe? 
**Error2:** this.blogs.push is not a function
```

My code looks like this:

```
export class BlogComponent {
  blogs: Array<blogType>;

  constructor() {
    this.blogs = new Array<blogType>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blogs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blogs")!);
  }

 addBlog(title: any, content: any) {

    let blog = new blogType(title.value, content.value);
    if (localStorage.getItem('blogs')) {
      this.blogs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('blogs')!);
    }

    this.blogs.push(blog); //error occurs because of that line. Runtime error
    localStorage.setItem('blogs', JSON.stringify(this.blogs));
    title.value = '';
    content.value = '';
    alert('Blog Added!');
  }
```

I am trying to take data from the "blog" array and push it to the "blogs" array in order to store it in the localstorage. Yet I get an error because of the folowing line: `this.blogs.push(blog);`

Comment: You're sure  `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blogs")!);` returns an array ?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the error you are receiving is related to the line in your code you are indicating;  the error **clearly** says `NgFor` which is in an HTML template, not a JavaScript function....

Comment: After the statement,  "this.blogs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('blogs')!)" try adding 'console.log(this.blogs)' and see what's gets printed

Comment: Added 'console.log(this.blogs)'  after line "this.blogs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('blogs')!)", error still occurs, but console shows what I typed:
{title: 'yrety', content: 'tryrt'}
content
: 
"tryrt"
title
: 
"yrety"
[[Prototype]] : Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the contents of LocalStorage for null before you parse it and assign to this.blogs:

```
ngOnInit() {
    var current = localStorage.getItem('blogs');
    if (current !== null) {
      this.blogs = JSON.parse(current);
    }
    console.log('this.blogs is: ' + this.blogs);
  }
```